# Is there a way to use Maven Scope 'provided' when deploying to WAR, but 'compile' when running in IDE?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, dependency-management

I am creating a Spring Boot application that will be running inside a Tomcat server. I am using the `@SpringBootApplication` tag on my main class, and in the pom.xml file I am using scope `compile` for the Tomcat dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This way, when running inside my IDE (IntelliJ), the application starts its own Tomcat server so I can easily test the application. When deploying to a WAR file I edit the pom.xml file and set the scope for tomcat to 'provided', since I load the WAR file into an existing Tomcat container on the server.

I create the WAR file by running `./mvnw clean package` from the commandline.

When setting the scope to 'provided' and running inside the IDE, I get the following error:

```
...
2017-05-02 10:40:19.529  WARN 14508 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [be.test.test.Test]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer$ErrorPageFilterConfiguration
2017-05-02 10:40:19.534 ERROR 14508 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7e1b02ea: startup date [Tue May 02 10:40:19 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ...
```

Is there some way to set this up in a way that I can run this in "test mode" in the IDE, but can create the WAR file without changing the pom.xml file? I have seen the scope "test" is also available, but from what I understand this is only used during Unit Testing? Or is that exactly what I am looking for?

Disclaimer:
I am *very* new to all of this, so bear with me if I'm getting all kinds of basics wrong and kindly point me to the concepts and technologies I should look into ;)

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to be able to load into Tomcat as a Servlet: https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-spring-boot-war-files -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>

            <!-- Use 'provided' when deploying to .WAR for Tomcat -->
                <!-- This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. -->
            <!-- Use 'compile'  when working in IntelliJ for development -->
                <!-- This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects. -->
            <scope>compile</scope>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<!-- Commenting this out to deploy to the existing Tomcat server: https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>-->


</project>
```

Comment: Why not always setting to `provided` and what do you mean by `When deploying to a WAR file...` how is your packaging being set ? Can you show your pom file?

Comment: Ah, I didn't explain why just using 'provided' doesn't work. I added it, along with the pom.xml file and an explanation on how I create my WAR file.